# how to search dictionary by Key using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to search value in dictionary using linq

```
HiddenField hf_resID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hf_resID");
int resID = Convert.ToInt32(hf_resID.Value);
////get GroupID
var value = from di in Resources_and_Groups
    where (di.Key.ToString() == resID.ToString())
    select di.Value;
//get controller from Repeater
DropDownList ddlGroup = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlGroup");

//ddlGroup.SelectedValue = value.ToString();
```

Comment: You are. Now, how do you want **us** to help you?

Comment: Have you tried `di[hf_resID.Value]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need Linq? Perhaps you can provide more information.

This should work:

```
var value = Resources_and_Groups[resID.ToString()];
```

Comment: Or use dict.TryGetValue(key, out val) to handle instances where there is no value available.